# Boas práticas com grid system do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, semântica

Seria uma boa prática declarar grids dentro de grids utilizando o twitter bootstrap e isto pode afetar a responsividade do código?

Exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">  <!-- 12 colunas -->
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-6 column"> <!-- divide aqui -->
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-4 column"> <!-- divide denovo 6 -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 column">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 column">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problema não tem nenhum, mas é claro que se uma coluna já é estreita, adicionar mais 12 dentro dela não vai ficar visualmente interessante (no desktop).

Comment: Não tem problemas então, dividir uma de 6 em duas de 3(por exemplo)?

Comment: Não. O sistema de grids possui o tamanho relativo ao elemento pai. Ou seja, ele se adequa automaticamente. Além disso, quando utilizado na versão mobile, as colunas se comportam como linhas da mesma forma. Então resumidamente, pode usar sem medo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que seja uma boa prática sim, sempre apliquei grid, dentro de grid, mesmo antes de conhecer o bootstrap. Utilizava o http://960.gs como referência.

E fazer grid dentro de grid não afeta a responsividade, ou seja o layout continua responsivo.

Comment: Você costuma inserir 12 colunas dentro de cada coluna?
Tem alguma dica para evitar problemas?

Comment: @MarceloAymone Depende do layout. Mas costumo sim usar até 12 colunas. Mas geralmente gosto de usar 3 ou 4 colunas de 300px ou 220px. Gosto muito de utilizar essa página como referência. http://960.gs/demo.html

Answer (score 2):

É normal utilizar grid dentro de grid, é assim que o sistema funciona. Exemplo:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-6"></div> <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

> mas o html fica ruim, poluído e pouco legível.

Essa é outra questão, quando eu uso o Bootstrap, não consigo passar o Grid System dessa forma em minha opinião isso fica extremamente feio. Qual a solução nesses casos? Utilize um pré-compilador CSS!

**style.scss**

```
#principal{
 @extend .col-md-12;
}

.menu{
 @extend .col-md-6;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="principal">
   <div class="menu"></div> <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

Imagine sem usar pré-compilador como ficaria se eu tivesse uma diferença no css

**Não recomendo:**

```
<style>
#principal{
 background-color: black;
}

.menu{
 background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<div class="col-md-12" id="principal">
   <div class="col-md-6 menu"></div> <div class="col-md-6 menu"></div>
</div>
```

Nesse caso eu só apliquei uma regra de cores, mas conforme nosso projeto cresce ficaria horrível dar manutenção em um projeto Bootstrap sem utilizar algum pré-compilador. No exemplo utilizei a syntaxe do SaSS, porém, vai do gosto de cada um :)

Answer (score 1):

Grids dentro de Grids podem até manter a responsividade e não comprometer o layout, mas o html fica ruim, poluído e pouco legível. 
Ao finalizar um html eu sempre procuro cortar/retirar "DIVs" desnecessárias e decorativas, transferindo "IDs" e classes quando for preciso.